# Is there a way to insert new record for iceberg table using pyiceberg api?

Tags: python, hive, insert, apache-iceberg

I want to insert new record to an iceberg table using pyiceberg API. Connection was established and I can fetch the existing records in the table using the displayData() fun. However, I couldn't find enough documentation to insert new record/update etc.

Can someone help me how to achieve this if the feature is available?

```
from pyiceberg.catalog import load_catalog
import numpy as np
import pyarrow as pa
from pyiceberg.io.pyarrow import PyArrowFileIO
from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager
from pyiceberg.schema import Schema
from pyiceberg.types import TimestampType, FloatType,  DoubleType, StringType, NestedField, StructType
import pandas as pd
from pyarrow import Table as pa_table



catalog_name = "xxxx"
schema_name = "zz"
table_name = "yyy"


catalog = load_catalog(name=catalog_name, **{ 
    "uri":"thrift://hive metastore.ip.adress:port",
    "s3.endpoint": "https://end/point/api/url:port",
    "py-io-impl": "pyiceberg.io.pyarrow.PyArrowFileIO",
    "s3.access-key-id": "myaccesskey",
    "s3.secret-access-key": "secretaccesskey" 
})

iceberg_table = catalog.load_table(f'{schema_name}.{table_name}')
def displayData():

    
    print("Table Schema:\n", iceberg_table.schema())
    scan = iceberg_table.scan()
    print(scan.to_pandas())


def InsertNewRecord(new_record_data):
    
   pass


# Example usage:
new_record_data = {
    "sensor_name": "M2",
    "reading_time": "2023-10-2 11:48:16+00:00",
    "value": 20
}

# displayData()
InsertNewRecord(new_record_data)
```

Comment: Hey @lion. PyIceberg 0.5.0 does not support writes yet. That's scheduled for 0.6.0 that's expected this month

Comment: okay, thanks for your respond.